# Calling order in recursive generator?

Tags: python, recursion, generator

```
def powerset(seq):
    """
    Returns all the subsets of this set. This is a generator.
    """
    if len(seq) <= 1:
        yield seq
        yield []
    else:
        for item in powerset(seq[1:]):
            yield [seq[0]]+item
            yield item
```

Above is a recursive generator that can generate all power set. For example,

```
powerset([1,2,3])=>[1, 2, 3][2, 3][1, 3][3][1, 2][2][1][]
```

Yet I'm confused with how it works. It seems it's yielding in this order:

```
powerset([1,2,3])=>powerset([2,3])=>powerset([3])
```

which is outside=>inside, contrary to what "recursive" means in my understanding, inside=>outside,for example recursively solve factorial(5):

```
factorial has been called with n = 5
factorial has been called with n = 4
factorial has been called with n = 3
factorial has been called with n = 2
factorial has been called with n = 1
intermediate result for  2  * factorial( 1 ):  2
intermediate result for  3  * factorial( 2 ):  6
intermediate result for  4  * factorial( 3 ):  24
intermediate result for  5  * factorial( 4 ):  120
120
```

So how to understand recursive generator?

Comment: To be recursive means to call itself.  `powerset` calls `powerset` inside of itself, so it is recursive.

Comment: @zondo yeah, what I'm confused with is, why the outmost yield is called first?

Comment: Function with recursive functionality works like a `stack` , so the first call will be outputed last

Comment: For your example, the first thing yielded is `[1]` + the first thing yielded by `powerset([2, 3])`.  `powerset([2, 3])` first yields `[2]` + `powerset([3])`.  So far, our first yield is `[1] + [2] + powerset([3])`.  That can be simplified to `[1, 2] + powerset([3])`.  `powerset([3])` yields first `[3]` because `len(seq) <= 1`.  Therefore, the first thing yielded is `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @zondo So will the powerset([3]) be called several times?

Comment: Yes.  It is called, then it calls itself which calls itself.  That's three times just for the first list.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your generator implements a backtracking algorithm: Before any `yield` is being reached, a number of recursive calls has been made. The `yield` calls appearing first in the program text will only be made once the recursion has been nesting deep enough for the remaining list to be of length 1, and only after that will the `for` loop be entered because that requires the innermost generator to yield something.

```
powerset([1,2,3]) level 1: seq1=[1,2,3]
| powerset([2,3]) level 2: seq2=[2,3]
| | powerset([3]) level 3: seq3=[3]
| | | yield [3]   3: yield seq3, becomes item2 in level 2
| | yield [2,3]   2: yield [seq2[0]] + item2, becomes item1 in level 1
| yield [1,2,3]   1: yield [seq1[0]] + item1, output
| yield [2,3]     1: yield item1, output
...
```

The short innermost produced sequences will appear in the output of the outermost call only by being "bubbled up" through the last line of the `for` loop. Before that is reached, the combination with `seq[0]` is yielded.

If you want to have the output the other way around, try exchanging the two `yield` lines inside the loop.

Comment: '... that requires the innermost generator to yield something.' So why [1,2,3] and [2,3] is output first but not the innermost yield [3] and []?

Comment: See my attempt at a timeline of yielded values "bubbling up".

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:

This is the recursion part:

```
for item in powerset(seq[1:]):
            yield [seq[0]]+item
            yield item
```

Basically this means

```
for every result in a smaller powerset:

    return the not used value + the result

    then return result alone
```

So if we look at powerset([3]); this returns first [3] and then [] because it has length 1

powerset([2,3]) calls powerset([3]) and then does:

1. return 2 and *first* item of powerset([3]) (=[2,3])
2. only return *first* item of powerset([3]) (=[3])
3. return 2 and *second* item of powerset([3]) (=[2])
4. return *second* item of powerset([3]) (=[])

This results in `[2,3] [3] [2] []`

If we call powerset([1,2,3]) the same thing happens

1. 1+[2,3]
2. [2,3]
3. 1+[3]
4. [3]
5. 1+[2]
6. [2]
7. 1+[]
8. []